# An Australian staying in UK applying for French working visa

Tags: france, resident-permit, australian-citizens, working-holiday-visas

I am an Australian citizen currently staying with family in England. However, I wish to obtain a French Working visa so I can live my dream of working in a ski resort. Is it possible for me to apply for a French working visa while I'm currently in the UK?

I've looked into this a bit and I'm confused as to whether I can get around this or not. I have two options.

Apply for the visa to the French consul in Sydney Australia where the problem arises with the meeting as im not sure if they will let me apply to the Sydney office then have my appointment in London.

Apply to the French consul here in London where the issue is that I don't have a residence permit. Which is required when applying online.

Extra information: I have a youth mobility visa for the UK

If anyone has had a similar kind of problem please provide me with some insight.

Comment: Did you ask at the French consulate?

Answer (score 2):

No one else has answered this yet, so I am going to answer based on what I was told at the visa processing centre in London. I'm aware that you may no longer be requiring this assistance, but perhaps it can be useful in the future for somebody else.

The answer is **maybe** (see below), but you should try to speak to TLSContact (the contractor which handles French visa applications) as well as the embassy in Sydney, because:

**Residents in the UK can apply for French visas through the London embassy if they have a valid residence permit in the UK.** The residence permit **must be currently valid and expiring < 10 days after the date the application is given** (the day you show up for your appointment in London). This will be checked by the front desk people when you first enter TLScontact, after being searched and after sitting in the front queue.

**Source of this response:**

I have no online source for this. I was also in a similar situation and I had no idea, and had to go and hope for the best. I was given this information by a gentleman at the front desk who checked my documents. In my case, my student visa was expiring in 10 days (although it was actually revoked by a border control officer, and I was in the country on a tourist visa-on-arrival). I was still allowed to process my application, in spite of the fact that my application was against the rules in a strict sense. This is why I encourage you to check whether they are willing to help you.

**What you should do in this situation:**

There is no publicly available phone number for TLScontact. You would first create your application [here](https://www.tlscontact.com/gbLON2fr/login.php?l=en). You would then submit your application and then follow the link in your account to send an enquiry to TLSContact. In your enquiry you would give a brief overview and request urgently that they call you on your phone number. Several hours later, they usually comply. You would ask your question to that individual.

In parallel, you should email or call the consulate in Sydney with the same question.

Source: [here](https://www.tlscontact.com/gbLON2fr/login.php?l=en)

> 2- WHO CAN APPLY FOR A VISA
>   Citizens from some non-EU countries are required to hold a visa when travelling to the Schengen area – to apply here, you must be resident in the UK.

I take this to mean 'ordinarily resident', for which a tourist visa (your situation) would not count. You'd need to be in the UK on a work permit or student visa. *But I may be wrong on that front, and perhaps they can make exceptions*, so you should call them.

Conjecture alert: I think this is because your passport is taken during your application, and if you don't have a BRP (biometric residence permit), a tourist would effectively have no identification and would be impossible for the UK to deport. I think this is why they don't want to process people who are nonresidents, but that's just my guess.

Comment: Actually, there is a more general principle in the Schengen codes that consulates should only serve those who *reside* in their territory.  The UK and the US, for example, do not share this principle.  For some Schengen countries, at least, this is also true of passport applications for their own citizens.  As a nonresident of the UK, a Dutch/US dual citizen can get a new US passport at a US consulate in the UK, but as a resident of New York, the same person cannot get a new Dutch passport at the Dutch consulate in Los Angeles.